# Replacing web server used by legacy WCF app using TransportWithMessageCredential

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, .net, web-services, wcf

I have a Ruby on Rails app that needs to replace an existing SOAP web service to allow a legacy third-party application to call into it. There is an existing WSDL with a single operation I need to reproduce. I don't have access to the server on which the existing web service runs so I cannot hit it with `curl` and inspect its response.

The legacy application is .NET 4.0 using WCF with SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential. I have an application that simulates it but I do not have access to the source code.

The application does connects to my SOAP service to make a RequestSecurityToken request using a UserName credential. So far so good.

I've read this: http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/WS-Trust.pdf and http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512/ws-secureconversation-1.3-os.html. There are a great deal of optional elements to the response. I found this question: [How to pass message credentials - TransportWithMessageCredential - No credentials in the SOAP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290204/how-to-pass-message-credentials-transportwithmessagecredential-no-credential) which includes a RequestSecurityTokenResponse which worked for the poster. I have used that response as a template:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RSTR/SCT</a:Action>
        <a:RelatesTo>#{message_id}</a:RelatesTo>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>#{xml_datetime(response_created_at)}</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>#{xml_datetime(response_expires_at)}</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
            <t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType>
            <t:RequestedSecurityToken>
                <c:SecurityContextToken u:Id="uuid-#{security_context_token_id}-8" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
                    <c:Identifier>urn:uuid:#{security_context_token}</c:Identifier>
                </c:SecurityContextToken>
            </t:RequestedSecurityToken>
            <t:RequestedAttachedReference>
                <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI="\#uuid-#{security_context_token_id}-8"/>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </t:RequestedAttachedReference>
            <t:RequestedUnattachedReference>
                <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    <o:Reference URI="urn:uuid:#{security_context_token}" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct"/>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </t:RequestedUnattachedReference>
            <t:RequestedProofToken>
                <t:ComputedKey>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/CK/PSHA1</t:ComputedKey>
            </t:RequestedProofToken>
            <t:Entropy>
                <t:BinarySecret u:Id="uuid-#{binary_secret_id}-9" Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce">#{binary_secret}</t:BinarySecret>
            </t:Entropy>
            <t:Lifetime>
                <u:Created>#{xml_datetime(response_created_at)}</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>#{xml_datetime(response_expires_at)}</u:Expires>
            </t:Lifetime>
            <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
        </t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

When I have the legacy application connect to my web service I can confirm that the response has content built by the template above and I can confirm that the XML output appears to be valid (no namespace errors or tag mismatches). My web server is returning a 200 response code.

The legacy application uses the following settings:

```
WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

The client created off the wsHttpBinding has the following:

```
if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol == (SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls))
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
if (!this.cbServerCertificateValidation.Checked)
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (RemoteCertificateValidationCallback)
   {
      return true;
   };
```

When the web service call is made a CommunicationException is raised:

```
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
```

There is a question about this as well: [The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763592/the-communication-object-system-servicemodel-channels-servicechannel-cannot-be) which indicates the client believes the server has faulted somehow. I thing this is because my RequestSecurityTokenResponse is either missing elements or has elements in it that WCF is not expecting.

Does anyone know what elements WCF is expecting given this setup? Is there more information I need to provide? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also think it could be a server-side problem. Invoking such a WCF service is usually done using a proxy class. We need to provide an additional set of username/password, and nothing more than trust the server certificate(as you add ServerCertificateValidationCallback manually).
Please refer to my example of calling this kind of WCF service.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119756/use-both-certificate-and-username-for-client-authentication-in-wcf-with-basichtt/55139087#55139087

Comment: It's definitely a server-side problem (the server is the part I'm replacing). The client is rejecting the RequestSecurityTokenResponse and I don't know why. I do not have the ability to change the client (another company is responsible for that and are unwilling/unable to make any changes). I should add that the WCF web client and the server will be running in an environment where the server is considered "trusted" and the X.509 certificate is ignored.